# Laravel - Request::is() doesn't work as it should

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 different titles

users

agencies

end customers

inactive

and i have only one view (one laravel.blade.php file) with this code

```
@section('title')
    @if (Request::is('/admin/users'))
        Alle Benutzer
    @elseif(Request::is('/admin/agencies'))
        Agenturen
    @elseif(Request::is('/admin/endcustomers'))
        Endkunden
    @else
        Inactive
    @endif
@endsection
```

and in my layout i have

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
```

and in my routes i have

```
Route::get('/admin/users', 'AdminController@showUsers');
Route::get('/admin/agencies', 'AdminController@showAgencies');
Route::get('/admin/endcustomers', 'AdminController@showEndCustomers');
Route::get('/admin/inactive', 'AdminController@showInactiveUsers');
```

And which ever site i call the title is always Inactive
What am i doing wrong....why the title doesn't change?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: 5.3 i fixed the problem with leaving the / at the beginning of route...now all works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't use the "Request"  in the view.

I suggest you send the title from the controller like this:

```
return view('%the name of the view%', ['title'=>"%Your title%"]);
```

Then in the view, you can put this

```
<title> {{$title }} </title>
```

Answer (score 0):

you've got to **echo** the title in the @section.

```
@section('title')
    @if (Request::is('/admin/users'))
        echo("Alle Benutzer");
    @elseif(Request::is('/admin/agencies'))
        echo("Agenturen");
    @elseif(Request::is('/admin/endcustomers'))
        echo("Endkunden");
    @else
        echo("Inactive");
    @endif
@endsection
```

Comment: Oh yes, I just remembered. Well, that's strange. Did you try without the conditions to debug?

Comment: I'm trying this on my machine. It really is an interesting problem. I'll get back to you right away!

Comment: So, I've tried your issue on my localhost and it's working.

I searched further on the laravel Doc and this page gives an exact exemple of what you're trying to do. (The first exemple in the page) https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade

Comment: yes...i went throught documentation all should be ok....maybe if you could connect with teamviewer on my machine to check it...maybe i'm doing something wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126552/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-alaoui-zoubair).

Comment: I have Laravel 5.3

Comment: I have figured it out what was the problem....the absolute path...i had to delete the slash at the beginning like this @if (Request::is('admin/users'))

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in **Blade (view)**:

```
@switch(\Route::current()->getName())
    @case('/admin/users')
        Alle Benutzer
    @break

    @case('/admin/agencies')
        Agenturen
    @break

    @case('/admin/endcustomers')
        Endkunden
    @break

    @default
        Inactive
@endswitch
```

Comment: Please explain that further. How could that code be integrated into the Blade template?